# sum of the series $\frac{2^n+3^n}{6^n}$ from $n=1$ to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Find the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^n+3^n}{6^n}=?$

My thoughts: find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^n$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 3^n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 6^n$ (although I don't know how yet...)

Then, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^n+3^n}{6^n}= \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^n}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 3^n} + \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 3^n}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 6^n}$, am I on the right track? I really don't know how else to solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: No, this is not a good way to go. Clearly, all those series are divergent so that won't work.

Comment: More importantly, it is totally false that $\sum (a/b) = \sum a / \sum b$.  That's kind of like expecting $(1/2 + 1/2)$ to be the same as $(1+1)/(2+2)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Hint:*
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^n+3^n}{6^n}
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{6^n}
+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{3^n}{6^n}
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2}{6}\right)^n
+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{3}{6}\right)^n
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{2^n + 3^n}{6^n}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty (\frac{2}{6})^n + \sum_{i=1}^\infty (\frac{3}{6})^n=\frac{1}{2}+1=\frac{3}{2}$$

sums from forumla of geometric series $1/3^n$ and  $1/2^n$