# Test for series Convergence: $\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\frac {3^n+2^n}{6^n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, geometric-progressions

Does this series converge?
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\frac {3^n+2^n}{6^n}}$$
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\frac {3^n+2^n}{6^n}} = \sum^\infty_{n=1}{\frac {3^n}{6^n}+\frac {2^n}{6^n}}=\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\frac {1}{2^n}+\frac {1}{3^n}}$$
Since $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac {1}{2^n}$ and $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac {1}{3^n}$ both converge, must its sum also converge?

Comment: Correct, and you should be able to find the value of the sum

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct.

Comment: so the sum of two convergent series convergent?

Comment: See also: [sum of the series $\frac{2^n+3^n}{6^n}$ from $n=1$ to $\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1712458). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum%5E%5Cinfty_%7Bn%3D1%7D%7B%5Cfrac%20%7B3%5En%2B2%5En%7D%7B6%5En%7D%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if $\sum a_n,\sum b_n$ converge to $A$ and $B$ then $\sum (a_n+b_n)$ converges to $A+B$.

Given $\delta>0$ you can find $N_1,N_2$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^Na_n$ is within $\delta/2$ of $A$ if $N>N_1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^Nb_n$ is within $\delta/2$ of $B$ if $N>N_2$.

Now if $N>\max(N_1,N_2)$ you have $\sum_{n=1}^N(a_n+b_n)=\sum_{n=1}^Na_n+\sum_{n=1}^Nb_n$ is within $\delta$ of $A+B$.